# Testing results for async calls made in useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-hooks

I'm trying to assert that my Custom hook returns some data from an API when it mounts.

The code looks like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { findByStatus } from '../../services/AssignmentService';
import Assignment from '../../models/Assignment';
import AssignmentList from './AssignmentList';

type AssignmentListApiHookTuple =  [Assignment[], React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>];

export const useAssignmentListApi = (initialStatus: string = ''): AssignmentListApiHookTuple => {
  const [assignments, setAssignments]  = React.useState<Assignment[]>([]);
  const [status, setStatus] = React.useState<string>(initialStatus);
  React.useEffect(
    () => {
      findByStatus(status).then((res) => { setAssignments(res); });
    },
    [status],
  );

  return [
    assignments,
    setStatus,
  ];
};

const AssignmentListContainer = (props: { status: string }) => {
  const [assignments, setStatus] = useAssignmentListApi(props.status);

  return (<AssignmentList assignments={assignments} />);
};

export default AssignmentListContainer;
```

and the test looks like this:

```
test('useAssignmentApi correctly sets the state', () => {
    const mockReturnValue = [{some: 'value'}];
    (AssignmentService.findByStatus as jest.Mock<any, any>)
      .mockResolvedValue(mockReturnValue);

    // Setup a dummy component to pass the custom hook
    const TestHook = (props: { callback: Function }) => {
      const { callback } = props;
      callback();
      return <div />;
    };

    const testHook = (callback: Function) => mount(<TestHook callback={callback}/>);

    const component = testHook(() => {
      const [assignments, setAssignment] = useAssignmentListApi('new');
     setTimeout(() => { expect(assignments).toEqual(mockReturnValue); } , 10);

    });
  });
```

This test work with any delayt in setTimeout(), but always fails if i don't put in the setTimeout there? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: remove `async` keyword

Comment: That didn't help @codekaizer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up using [react-testing-library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro) and utilizing their `waitForElement` api to wait until I found an element/text that I'd see after the data fetch was done, and then asserting on the rendered value.

The tests now look like :

```js
 it('renders the list with the data returned by api', async () => {
    const mockReturnValue = [
      {
        some: "value",
      }
    ];
    (AssignmentService.findByStatus as jest.Mock<any, any>)
      .mockResolvedValue(mockReturnValue);

    const container = render(<AssignmentListContainer status="new"/>);

    // wait until api fetches data
    await waitForElement(() => container.queryByText('Text I would expect after api call'));

    // make assertions
    expect(container.asFragment()).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
```